# ieframe.dll error while running silverlight application in IE9

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0, internet-explorer-9

I've recently updated my Internet Explorer version from 8 to 9. Now, I'm getting the following exception
[image]

This is kind of weird. Following are the re-producing steps.

1. Open a Silverlight application [Currently, using Silverlight 4].
2. Use Clean, Build and Run. [The above mentioned exception occurs]
3. Now, again hit refresh in browser. [The application loads and works correctly.]

This is same for both **Blend** as well as **Visual Studio**.

Note: Once, you got it working after the second time refresh technique it won't occur until you Clean and Build the solution once again. Before, it shows this Internet cannot display the webpage "ieframe.dll error" is displayed in the Tab header of IE.

How to resolve this? or is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this IE9 Beta bug has been reported to Microsoft when debugging against the local VS Web Server. The IE team is investigating. Thanks!

(PS: Report IE9 bugs at http://connect.microsoft.com/IE)

Comment: A temporary workaround involves modifying the HOSTS file so LOCALHOST doesn't attempt to use IPv6: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/internet-explorer-9-breaks-localhost

Comment: Fixed in IE9 RC, available today.